# BindingResult does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, restful-architecture

I have designed a Restful controller in Spring-Boot. it has a method for persisting book objects (with post method) which works perfectly unless you send invalid input (for instance if you send a non integer value to an integer field). The problem here is that instead fulfilling BindingResult object spring throws HttpMessageNotReadableException exception. Therefore, I cannot handle/process binding errors and further validation.

What I need is that How I can tell spring to does not throw any exception while it is binding request to object, So I can use bindingResult.hasErrors() and handle it in my own way.

Note: I don't want to handle Spring produced object.

here is my code:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Book> saveBook (
        @RequestBody Book book, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request ) {
    if ( bindingResult.hasErrors() == true )
        throw new RestArgumentValidationException( bindingResult, request.getRequestURI() );
    return new ResponseEntity<>( bookRepository.save( _book ), HttpStatus.CREATED );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you must put validation annotation in your book objects, like this:

```
public class Book {
  @Size(min = 5, max = 10)
  int height;
}
```

Then you should put @Valid in your objects which need to validate to let Spring know.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Book> saveBook (
        @RequestBody @Valid Book book, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request ) {
    if ( bindingResult.hasErrors() == true )
        throw new RestArgumentValidationException( bindingResult, request.getRequestURI() );
    return new ResponseEntity<>( bookRepository.save( _book ), HttpStatus.CREATED );
}
```

Comment: I've done what you've mentioned yet it still throws the exception.

Comment: @user335870 I am facing the same problem. Are you able to resolve this issue?